# OnClick() event in dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, asp-classic

I have a dropdown menu. When I click on "Italian" in the dropdown, I want the content for Italian to show. Basically, what I want is to set the action to IT when I select Italian from the dropdown. How might I apprach this?

```
 <% action = Request.QueryString("action") %>

    <form name="contentchanger" action="/" method="post">
         <select name="flag" name="flag">
              <option value="Choose" selected="selected">Choose</option>
              <option value="italian" onclick="what code i should use here?">Italian</option>
         </select>
    </form>
    <a href="?action=FR">FR</a>
    <a href="?action=IT">IT</a>

    <%
    if action = "IT" Then  
      Response.Write("<p>This is italian</p>") 
    else if  action = "FR" Then  
      Response.Write("<p>This is French</p>") 
    end if
    end if
    %>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is better to use onchange event on the select box. Onclick doesn't work well in all browsers. Bind a javascript function to the onchange event that changes the url of the a element (or redirect to the correct url if you want to change it instantly).

Something like this should work. I recomment using a javascript libary like jquery if you want to do more interactive client side functionality

changeLanguage()

```
<select onchange="changeLanguage(this.value)">
    <option value="Choose" selected="selected">Choose</option>
    <option value="IT" >Italian</option>
    <option value="FR" >France</option>
</select>

<a id="url" href="?action=IT">IT</a>
```

Javascript:

```
function changeLanguage(language) {
    var element = document.getElementById("url");
    element.value = language;
    element.innerHTML = language;
}
```

**Update:**

Code I used for my test. This works in the most recent versions of chrome, firefox and ie.

```
<html>
<head>
 <script>
  function changeLanguage(language) {
   var element = document.getElementById("url");
   element.value = language;
   element.innerHTML = language;
  }
 </script>
</head>
<body>
<select onchange="changeLanguage(this.value)">
    <option value="Choose" selected="selected">Choose</option>
    <option value="IT" >Italian</option>
    <option value="FR" >France</option>
</select>

<a id="url" href="?action=IT">IT</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi Mark, thanks for your reply..I have tried the code and I am receiving and error :/

Comment: try it on IE and you will see the following error: null is null or not an object

Comment: Strange, it works fine for me in IE 8. As far as i know this functionality should be compatible with older versions of ie aswell. You could try to rewrite this functionality with jQuery. This is a great javascript libary that avoids a lot of browser compatibility problems. Putting javascript in a external js file can help aswell or escape it with <![CDATA[ (code) ]]> tags for old browsers.

Comment: Works for me on Chrome Version 48.0.2564.116 m.